# Using Comparable interface to prohibit comparison between inherited types

Tags: java, generics

I am going through the "Java Generics and Collections" book by Naftalin. I want to check my understanding regarding a point that they make in Chapter 3.

They explain about how the `Comparable` interface allows us to control what types we can compare with one another. In the below code example that they provide, they say that it is not possible to compare *Apple* with *Orange*. To be precise, this is what they say:

> Since Apple implements `Comparable<Apple>`, it is clear that you can compare apples with apples, but not with oranges.

But as you can see, on the last line of the `main` method, we are able to do so, because the `compareTo` from the base class ends up being called. So I presume the solution to this would be to duplicate the implementation of the `compareTo` method by moving it to each of the *Apple* and *Orange* classes? And removing it from the base *Fruit* class? Or is there a better way to do this?

```
abstract class Fruit {
    protected String name;
    protected int size;

  protected Fruit(String name, int size) {
    this.name = checkNotNull(name);
    this.size = size;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o instanceof Fruit) {
      Fruit that = (Fruit) o;
      return this.name.equals(that.name) && this.size == that.size;
    }
    return false;
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return name.hashCode() * 29 + size;
  }

  protected int compareTo(@Nullable Fruit that) {
    if (this.size > that.size) {
      return 1;
    } else if (this.size < that.size) {
      return -1;
    } else return 0;
  }
  }
}

class Apple extends Fruit implements Comparable<Apple> {
  public Apple(int size) {
    super("Apple", size);
  }

  @Override
  public int compareTo(Apple apple) {
    return super.compareTo(apple);
  }
}

class Orange extends Fruit implements Comparable<Orange> {
  protected Orange(int size) {
    super("Orange", size);
  }

  @Override
  public int compareTo(Orange orange) {
    return super.compareTo(orange);
  }
}

class TestFruit {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Apple apple1 = new Apple(1);
    Apple apple2 = new Apple(2);
    Orange orange1 = new Orange(1);
    Orange orange2 = new Orange(2);

    List<Apple> apples = List.of(apple1, apple2);
    List<Orange> oranges = List.of(orange1, orange2);

    // Both of these work as expected
    System.out.println(Collections.max(apples)); // Apple{name=Apple, size=2}
    System.out.println(Collections.max(oranges)); // Orange{name=Orange, size=2}

    // But now, as expected, when you try to create a mixed list, it will no longer work
    List<Fruit> mixed = List.of(apple1, orange2);
    // Compile error on the below line
    System.out.println(Collections.max(mixed));

    // But this also works now, because compareTo from the Fruit class
    // is being used here.
    System.out.println(apple1.compareTo(orange1)); // -1
  }
}
```

Comment: Note you couldn't do that if `main` was in a separate package.

Comment: But that's not the point of this. The various classes could be made public and placed in separate files, and then any `main` would be able to do that. 

@rgbk21, you are right, if you deleted the `Fruit` implementation and implemented inside the Apple and Orange, you wouldn't be able to do the `compareTo` at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. A class has method `compareTo(Fruit)` doesn't mean it implements `Comparable<Fruit>`. Only the opposite is correct.
2. In java API, method requiring comparison is based on `Comparable` interface, instead of checking if the class has `compareTo` method.

Since `Fruit` does not implements `Comparable<Fruit>`(it is a design problem if it implements), what the book say is correct. You can see `Collections.max` can't be called with `List<Fruit>`.

#### IMO, what make us confuse is the method name `compareTo` in `Fruit`.

- The name is ambiguous to `Comparable` method,
  So by convention, we should name a method `compareTo` only when we implements `Comparable`.
- Wrong method may be called due to static binding

  ```
  // Apple#compareTo is called
  System.out.println(apple1.compareTo(apple2));
  Fruit fruitWhichIsApple2 = apple2;
  // Fruit#compareTo is called
  System.out.println(apple1.compareTo(fruitWhichIsApple2));
  ```

Although it is marked as `protected`(which avoid usage from other package class), it is much clear if we rename it to something else.

Comment: In your example, it will still be the `Apple` compareTo method which will be called - because it overrides Fruit's.

Comment: @RealSkeptic, please try https://ideone.com/HJiTIi